# UITapGestureRecognizer is not firing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

Why is `swipeRightL` firing events and `tapR` is not?

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightL=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft)];
swipeRightL.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
swipeRightL.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightR];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightL];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapR=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTap)];
tapR.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
tapR.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapR];
```

Comment: are you sure it does not fire? have you add some `NSLog` traces into the two target actions? what is the layout of your views?

Comment: I did. And it just does not fire. I have the UIWeb subviews that span outside of the bounds of the main view, but I don't think it's a problem since the swipe is working.

Comment: are you tapping on the part of the view that lays within the bounds or outside of them? or in both cases it does not work? am I reading this correctly: you are adding subview to `UIWebView` and then adding gesture recognisers to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely your gestures are conflicting with one another. If you remove the swipe gesture does it work then?

You probably want to look at this delegate callback and return YES:

```
– gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
```

Comment: After adding tapR.delegate=self and returning YES in the callback, the onTap function is executing now.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple example code of "Simple Gesture Recognizers" prodives examples of tap, swipe and rotate gesture recognizers with all three types working within one view.  Check it out.  The example code uses storyboards to fully configure the view and its controller so the code is a bit sparse.  But you should be able to compare your coded configuration with the Xcode 'Attributes Inspector' and the 'Connections Inspector' to identify your differences.

Answer (score 0):

remove setups like:

tapR.numberOfTaps/Touches it's already 1 by default.

Try to implement delegate methods and check did they fired?

```
tapR.delegate = self;
```

`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:sender { return YES; }`

Also can you provide some details about views structure? For example, some another gestures (in scroll view or something) can be a reason why your swipe not firing.